# Different 'from' position after first animation iteration

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

https://jsfiddle.net/hk9qsayn/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="animate"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animate  {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  animation: wind 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes wind {
  0% {right:30%}
  100% {right:120%}
}
```

I want to start the first iteration from `right:30%`, but the second and all the other iteration should start from `right:-100px`. I've tried to use to animations but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit: forgot the `-`for the second start-position]

you could use multiple animations:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animate  {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  //right:-100px;
  animation: wind 2s linear, 2s blub 2s linear infinite; 
}


@keyframes wind {
  0% {right:30%}
  100% {right: 120%;
        background: yellow;
  }
}

@keyframes blub{
  0%{right: -100px;}
  100%{
    right: 120%;
    background:blue;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="animate"></div>
</div>
```

I added a change in bg-color so it's better to notice that the first animation runs one time, and the second one ("blub") runs infinite.
For the second animation to start a little bit later I added a delay of 2s

Comment: I forgot to add delay, when I used multiple animations. Thanks!